# How to remove a single item from asyncStorage in react native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a list of Items stored with asyncStorage, they all have the same key, using   `await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key)`  function its removes the entire list
of Items is there a way to remove only one single Item.

```
async removeItemValue(key) {
  
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    return true;
  }
  catch(exception) {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will do:

1. Get the list
2. remove the item
3. save the new list.

Something like:

```
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(theKey);
if (value !== null){
     var index = array.indexOf(theItem);
     if (index > -1){
         value.splice(index, 1);
     }
}
AsyncStorage.setItem(theKey, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
static removeItem(key: string, [callback]: ?(error: ?Error) => void)

refer : 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html